# Loading Schema in Spring XML

Tags: spring, validation

I'm trying to load an XSD file as a [Schema](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Schema.html) instance in my application context XML file. We're building it in java code, but I'd like to be injecting it.

Here's what the user class looks like if that'll clarify things.

```
class XmlBuilder {
    ...
    Schema schema; // set by spring

    public String createXml(Object param1) {
        // create xml
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

        try {
            validator.validate(documentSS);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // log and convert to a proper exception
        }
        return xml;
    }
}
```

The schema is in the app's classpath, I'm just having trouble loading it and creating the schema object. I can get this far

```
<bean id="schemaFactory" class="javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory" factory-method="newInstance">
    <constructor-arg value="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
</bean>
<bean id="xmlBuilder" class="XmlBuilder">
    <property name="schema">
        <bean factory-bean="schemaFactory" factory-method="newSchema">
            <!-- missing bit -->
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But I'm stuck on loading the file and passing it into the factory method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the [`ResourceSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/xml/transform/ResourceSource.html) class in 'org.springframework.ws:spring-xml'

```
<property name="schema">
    <bean class="org.springframework.xml.transform.ResourceSource">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:/schema.xsd"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```